# What did Johnny mean when he said "I trained myself to do it quietly" when making love with Cora?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, frankie-and-johnny

From Frankie and Johnny, when Johnny made love with Cora, he said "I trained myself to do it quietly. I've been to places where full-throated orgasm would be highly-inappropriate." I know he was in prison, but what does he mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just it, he was in prison. If a convict were to masturbate and orgasm noisily, chances would be *very* good that he would then be .... requested .... to perform on other convicts.

In prison:

If you are dominant, you'll be the one doing the .... requesting.

If you are submissive, or subservient, or not in a gang, prison either makes one celibate, or quiet, or someone's bitch.

A good movie example of this phenomenon is Shawshank Redemption.